# Where can I find libfltk.a?

Tags: c++, macos, fltk

I've downloaded and successfully installed `fltk-1.3.3` on OS X 10.11 (El Capitan).  Now I'm trying to compile some code with it:

`fltk-config --use-images --use-gl --compile my_file.cxx`

However, I get this error:

`clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/libfltk.a'`

I used to get these three errors:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/libfltk_images.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/libfltk_gl.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/libfltk.a'
```

... until I downloaded the raw source of these files from Github and manually put them in `/usr/local/lib`.

However, I can't seem to find any `libfltk.a` files on Github (or anywhere else on the web), which is preventing me from successfully compiling my program.  What can I do in this case?

I tried running a `make clean` again from the `fltk-1.3.3` directory in hopes of generating the `libfltk.a` file automatically, but no luck!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.libfltk.a%2F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=fs&trackid=sp-006&gfe_rd=ssl&ei=EL_jVuieFcWU-gXmzYzgBA

Comment: @KenWhite: I don't understand what this link means.

Comment: If you've downloaded, the from the internet, the libraries would not have been built yet.  At the top level you will find a file called README.OSX.txt.  Go through that and it will tell you how to do everything.

Comment: @cup Thank you for your suggestion.  I actually went back into the `README.OSX.txt` file and employed the `sudo make install`.  After this, running my `fltk-config --use-images --use-gl --compile my_file.cxx` command worked successfully!  Granted, I did run into one small problem with enum in the process, but I was able to resolve it with the advice given here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/41581.  Success!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem in **centos7**. missing `/usr/lib64/libfltk.a`. later found `fltk-static` is the package provide `libfltk.a`, its better to install `fltk`, `fltk-devel`, `fltk-fluid`, `fltk-static` to avoid any missing libraries.